# How to save data when parsing XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

I have a xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
<file name="a" size="559393"/>
<file name="b" size="1766945"/>
...
</list>
```

With SAX-parser I need to get the attribute values (in my case the name and size values of all tags **file**) and write in a collection for the further work my program.

How should I realize this? For each tag *file* to create an object with the fields *name* and *size*, and add it all to the *ArrayListObject*?

Comment: Doesn't sound so hard. Just define an object `MyFile` with members 'name' and 'size', an `ArrayList<MyFile>` to stuff everything in there and combine that with XML parsing

Comment: Yes. Hope using SAX parser, you are getting values of attributes name and size. You can create a bean/pojo class, let say here `FileInfo` with `name` and `size`. Over parsing and iterating XML values, you can set those value in `FileInfo` object and can be added to `ArrayList` object. You can use `Map`, if your file name is unique, to avoid `ArrayList` iteration for fetching values.

Comment: @Vish can you explain please: "you can use Map, if your file name is unique, to avoid ArrayList iteration for fetching values"

Comment: So `Map` is a key value pair collection. If file name is unique, the updated value is visible, else will be overwritten. Hope I am clear with following code.
`Map<String, FileInfo> map = new HashMap<String, FileInfo>();
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(name, size);
map.put(name, fileInfo);
`
To get file details, you need only `map.get(name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , you should have already object with name and size attributes , and while you in start element method , do something like this .

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
        String name = attributes.getValue("name");
        String size = attributes.getValue("size");
        file file = new file (name,size);
        list.add(file);
        }
      }
```